# Pandas sorting Pivot Table like in excel

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sorting, pivot-table

I am trying to sort pivot table (DF) same as in excel:
I have given df: (UPDATED):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": ["foo", "foo", "foo", "foo", "foo",
                         "bar", "bar", "bar", "bar","zz","zz"],
                  "B": ["one", "one", "one", "two", "two",
                         "one", "one", "two", "two","xy","zz"],
                   "Name":["Peter", "Amy", "Brian", "Amy", "Amy",
                         "Peter", "Brian", "Peter", "Brian","Brian","Brian"],
                  "Year": [2019, 2019, 2019, 2019,
                         2019, 2019, 2020, 2020,
                          2020,2019,2020],
                  "Values": [20, 4, 20, 5, 6, 6, 8, 9, 9,10,5]})
df_pivot = pd.pivot_table(df, values='Values', index=['Name','A', 'B'],
                    columns=['Year'], aggfunc=np.sum, fill_value=0, margins=True, margins_name="Totals")
```

Once I pivot it in a way I like it looks like this:

```
 Year            2019  2020  Totals
Name   A   B                      
Amy    foo one     4     0       4
           two    11     0      11
Brian  bar one     0     8       8
           two     0     9       9
       foo one    20     0      20
       zz  xy     10     0      10
           zz      0     5       5
Peter  bar one     6     0       6
           two     0     9       9
       foo one    20     0      20
Totals            71    31     102
```

Now the "fun" part begins..

I would like this df pivot table to be sorted on all index columns from left to right based on sum of values.

Let me explain.

Firstly I would like to sort this pivot table by column "Name" in descending order of "Totals" for each name, therefore I would calculate sum for Amy = 15, Brian = 52, Peter= 35.
From this I know that first column should be sorted Brian/Peter/Amy.

Now I do the same for second column "A", but first column "Name" is fixed.

i.e. for name Brian (which is on top) I now calculate totals for column "A" (I want to see whether foo/bar/zz should be first), therefore I calculate that Brian-Foo is equal to 20 and Brian-bar is equal to 8+9 and Brian-zz is 15, therefore we want to have Foo first for Brian in second column... and the same for rest indexed columns.

The output should look like this:

```
Year            2019  2020  Totals
Name   A   B                      
Brian  foo one    20     0      20 
       bar two     0     9       9
           one     0     8       8
       zz  xy     10     0      10
           zz      0     5       5
Peter  foo one    20     0      20
       bar two     0     9       9
           one     6     0       6
Amy    foo two    11     0      11
           one     4     0       4
Totals            71    31     102
```

So long story short, firstly I want to sort first column based on totals for items from that column and I want to fix it, then I want to sort second column for items from that column, but grouped as per first sorting etc.

Can you advise how to do this please?
I appreciate help a lot!

Thanks
Pawel